# Visual Studio Code Importing library 'AppiumLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppiumLibrary' in Mac

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, appium, robotframework

I am running Robot script using appium
I am using Mac, running pip3, as I am running in Python3

I am not sure what happen, I ran the following command in Comand line

```
pip3 install --upgrade robotframework-appiumlibrary
```

Everything seem okay. What could be wrong in my Visual studio code?

I do not have PIP because I do not have python2 installed

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch the python environment.

You have installed the package in the global python environment: `usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`.

But from your error picture, looks like you are using this python environment: `/Users/kah..../Python/3.8/bin`.

You can click the python interpreter from the bottom-right on the VSCode to switch the python environment. Or open the Command Palette(shortcut of Ctrl+Shift+`) and choose `Python: Select Interpreter`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by did a reinstall and I found out the bin folder of the python is not `/Users/kah..../Python/3.8/bin`

it should be
`/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/.../Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3`

I update the config path on mac for python and everything is resolved

You can find find the path by do a `brew install Python`